# display List/library url in display template

Tags: search, display-template

I am trying to add the url of libraries in the display template. ListUrl does not return any value.

So I thought using javascript to replace the filename to "". However it is throwing an error:

Object doesn't support property or method 'lastIndexOf' 
Any idea how to get the List Url in display templates?

```
var listPath = ctx.CurrentItem.Path; //Get Path
if (listPath.indexOf("Lists/") >= 0) {  //If contains List/
    var afterLists = listPath.substring(listPath.lastIndexOf("Lists/")+6); //get url after "Lists/"
    var listTitle = afterLists.split('/'); // split 
    listTitle[0] = listTitle[0].replace("_", " "); //get list title and replace _ with " "
    listTitle = listTitle[0]; // set list title in var
}
else  { //no Lists/ in path
    listPath = ""; //set empty
    listTitle = listPath;
} else if (listPath.indexOf("ces/") >= 0 && listPath.indexOf("Lists/") < 0) {  //If contains ces/ without lists
    var afterLists = listPath.substring(listPath.lastIndexOf("ces/")+4); //get url after "ces/"
    var listTitle = afterLists.split('/'); // split 
    listTitle[0] = listTitle[0].replace("_", " "); //get list title and replace "_" with " "
    listTitle = listTitle[0]; // set list title in var
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the OOTB managed property `ParentLink` which will have the URL of the list or document library.

In the `<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping` section of display template, add the `ParentLink` managed property.

After that, in your code you can use it as :

`ctx.CurrentItem.ParentLink`

or in your HTML as something like:

```
<a href="_#= ctx.CurrentItem.ParentLink =#_" title="All items">All items</a>
```

Comment: Oh man, I am not awake yet. I was going through the properties of ctx.CurrentItem and even I saw the returned url of "ParentLink", but my mind was stuck on javascript. Thanks man.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not seem to account for items stored inside folders. will just return the immediate parent folder, which being the root folder is fine, but will not always work